# Why are changes not allowed in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm in the process of upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2010, and for the most part it is going pretty smooth. One problem I'm running into is that if I put a break in the code, and try to make changes, I get an error saying that it's not allowed. This is something that I can't live without, so I'm hoping it can be fixed. Otherwise I'll be sticking with VS 2008 for a while longer.

[image: Error Message: Changes are not allowed in the following cases: when the debugger has been attached to an already running process. The code being debugged was optimized at build or run time. The assembly being debugged is loaded as domain neutral. The assembly being debugged was loaded through reflection.]

I have no add-ins, and the only extension I have is the GIT Source Control Manager.
I tried uninstalling the GIT Source Control Manager, but that didn't help the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably running a Release build.

Switch to the Debug configuration.

Comment: Weird, I don't know how that happened. I pulled it over from 2008 where it worked fine, and didn't change any settings. I'll remember to keep and eye open for this in the future. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: "and why doesn't the error mention this as a possible reason?".toUpper  

Sorry for my shouting. Vague error message is vague.

Comment: Because it's too obvious ;)  The message is only vague because those 4 listed reasons are obscure.  Which is the *exact* reason they are listed.  For every one programmer that wants an obvious reason added to the list, there'll be 100 programmers that will go "cheesus that's obvious, this dialog is stupid".  Or worse, spend an hour trying to figure out why it isn't in Debug mode (when it is) because that's the only reason that made sense to them.

Answer (score 5):

For ASP.NET applications, go to Project > App properties > Web > Debugging, and make sure that "enable and continue" is checked.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have Edit and Continue in the `Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue` menu enabled?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is due to Intellitrace setting

If Intellitrace is enabled make sure Intellitrace event only is checked

Otherwise this will not allow edit and continue..

If you will click on Intellitrace options you will see the warnings.

Comment: Hmm, Good to know! IntelliTrace events only is selected in mine, but it's good to know that's in there, in case anyone else has this issue. Thanks for this.

Comment: Where is the IntelliTrace setting in VS2010?