# Edit and Continue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461233/why-are-changes-not-allowed-in-visual-studio-2010), but of no help.

I have a solution with nearly 10 projects in it. I am able to edit the code while debugging the solution, but for 1 particular project (say "Defect.csproj"), I am not able to. I am receiving the error as [image]

I have compared the properties of this "Defect.csproj" project ith other project properties and everything is found to be same. In Debug and Build tab in properties, Configuration is Debug. Optimize code is off. Can anyone suggest me whats the problem with my solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are changes not allowed in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461233/why-are-changes-not-allowed-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: given the same link in my own question...

Comment: Still a dupe, Rapsalands. If you haven't found an appropriate answer to that question, may I suggest that you post a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)?

Comment: The question is similar that is why I gave the link. I am able to debug the solution but not a particular project, this information may be useful for some readers

Comment: Perhaps create a new project file from scratch. Or, maybe use Winmerge to compare settings of csproj file that works to this one that does not work.

Comment: @Valamas the Winmerge remark is the best one yet! 
MichaelPetrott Its not a duplicate since that seems to be a simple mistake by the poster of the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any special references on this project?

Using office references or delta lambda expressions can silently break the edit and continue functionality.

Also using some third party component winform items can really play havoc with edit and continue.

Also keep in mind that using linq breaks edit and continue fairly often and editing inside a try catch block on the active function is bad.